# Why does "request.getUserPrincipal().getName()" sometimes return a blank string?

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat, servlets, userprincipal

Has somebody an idea, why the `getName()` method of the `UserPrincipal` sometimes provides an empty String? Most of the time it returns the correct user name but not every time.

This behaviour does occur randomly. I can start the application, run the command and it works. The next time I start the application and run the command (exactly the same way as before!) it does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are all the locations of your app protected with a role?

Comment: Need more details, maybe a little example program. Are you using multi thread?

Comment: It seems that my problem is a little time-of-action-specific... I was using the request object from somewhere in my java classes (by using a static databean) and had the problem. Now I'm saving the URL direct in my databean at the beginning of a request and can therefore use it anytime I want. It works perfectly this way :)

Comment: Could you give more details and code examples for the situation you just described as "using a static databean"? It's possible that that is the key to answering this question.

Answer (score 1):

The part where you say, "...start the application and run the command..." is unclear.

What precisely are the steps involved?

HTTP is a text-based protocol.  If you capture and observe the requests and responses, I am certain you would observe a difference to which the behavior could be attributed.

My suggestion is to gather more detailed information to point you in the direction of the solution.